# Uppercase variables

Tags: batch-file

im trying to set two vars uppercase, can someone help with whats wrong with this?

The var1 and the var2 will be only one letter, for example a or d.
this doesnt give any error it just put the two var´s with the same letter.

By the way im using this in a bat file

thanks

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /p var1=a
SET /p var2=d
set /a "x = 1"
:while1
if %x% leq 2 (
if %x% EQU 1 (SET varvel=!var1!)
if %x% EQU 2 (SET varvel=!var2!)
    IF [%varvel%]==[] GOTO:invaliddat

        SET varvel=%varvel:a=A%
        SET varvel=%varvel:b=B%
        SET varvel=%varvel:c=C%
        SET varvel=%varvel:d=D%
        SET varvel=%varvel:e=E%
        SET varvel=%varvel:f=F%
        SET varvel=%varvel:g=G%
        SET varvel=%varvel:h=H%
        SET varvel=%varvel:i=I%
        SET varvel=%varvel:j=J%
        SET varvel=%varvel:k=K%
        SET varvel=%varvel:l=L%
        SET varvel=%varvel:m=M%
        SET varvel=%varvel:n=N%
        SET varvel=%varvel:o=O%
        SET varvel=%varvel:p=P%
        SET varvel=%varvel:q=Q%
        SET varvel=%varvel:r=R%
        SET varvel=%varvel:s=S%
        SET varvel=%varvel:t=T%
        SET varvel=%varvel:u=U%
        SET varvel=%varvel:v=V%
        SET varvel=%varvel:w=W%
        SET varvel=%varvel:x=X%
        SET varvel=%varvel:y=Y%
        SET varvel=%varvel:z=Z%

if %x% EQU 1 (set var1=!varvel!)
if %x% EQU 2 (set var2=!varvel!)
set /a "x = x + 1"
goto :while1
)
echo %var1% 
echo %var2%
Pause
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some code in your example.

Comment: no, but i can add the var1 and 2 set and an echo to test

Comment: Your code does not show how var1 and var2 are getting defined. Are we just supposed to take your word for it that it is getting assigned correctly?

Comment: Your right, already had it to the code

Comment: `echo %var1% & %var2%` that will never echo correctly.  The ampersand is a concatenation operator to run multiple commands on one line.

Comment: You have a delayed expansion problem.  You are inside a parenthesized code block so you need to reference your variables with exclamations instead of percent symbols.

Comment: Delayed expansion may help, as may [this](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#toUpper).

Comment: replace the % with ! it does the same thing. updated the code above with the changes

Comment: split them in sub´s and it working, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

a bit shorter:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
for %%a in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do set "var=!var:%%a=%%a!"
echo %var%
```

It seems strange to replace upper case letters by upper case letters, but it works.